# Use of undefined constant quantity-assumed quantity

Tags: php

I want to check that the quantity is more than given value it should get an message that "it is more quantity from the specified quantity". I am getting an error use of undefined constant qty-assumed qty in the order page.

```
<?php session_start();?>
        <?php
         $a=$_GET['id'];
         $k=0;
         $c_id;
        $link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("Can't Connect...");

        mysql_select_db("final_shop",$link) or die("Can't Connect to Database...");
 $uid=$_SESSION['userid'];
 $nm=$_SESSION['unm'];
 $id=$_SESSION['bid'];

 $t=$_SESSION['total'];
 $oid=0;

if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id=>$x)
    {   
        $p=$_SESSION['p'][$k];
        $qty=$_SESSION['qty'][$k];

        $bid_var=$x['b_id'];

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT b_subcat FROM `product` WHERE b_id=$bid_var") or die(mysql_error());
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo "<br>";

        $ii = 0;

        while($ii < $no_of_rows)
            {
                $c_id = mysql_result($result,$ii,'b_subcat');
                $c_id;
                $ii++;
                echo "<br>";
            }

        $query="INSERT INTO `order`(`u_id`, `u_nm`, `b_id`, `qty`, `c_id`, `total_amount`) VALUES ('".$uid."','".$nm."','".$x['b_id']."','".$qty."','".$c_id."','".$p."')";
        $k++;
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    }
    // error in this if condition
    if($qty <= qty)
                {
                mysql_query("UPDATE `product` SET qty = (qty - $qty ) WHERE b_id='$bid_var'") or die(mysql_error()) ;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "out of stock";
                }       
}

        echo "<script> alert('Your Order has been placed'); location='print.php?' </script>";
?>
```

Comment: The question is clearly, at you are `if`, what is qty? where define? you should use `define("QTY", YOU WANT)`. ref http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: The error message tells you which file and which line the error occurs on. It is clearly the `qty` constant, which is not defined. Also, `quantity` is not the same as `qty`! When you show us error messages **never** change what it says; show us the original error message, in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the line:

```
if ($qty <= qty)
```

In php every variable must start with `$`. (`if ($qty <= $someValue)`)

A variable name without a `$` is assumed to be a constant. The error message tells you that a constant must always be defined before using it. Defining such a constant can be done like this:

```
define("qty", 100); // define the constant
echo qty; // get value of constant; Note: there is no `$` involved
```